# How to post data to external url and get return json data by jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, cross-domain, http-post

I trying to post data to external website to get json data back by using jquery

problem is my response function not work, so how to solve it ?

my code sample

```
$.getJSON("http://externalweb.com/data.php?callback=?",
    function(result) {
        // this function is not work :(
        $("#result").html("test");
    }
);
```

Comment: Do a google search for `ajax cross-domain-policy`!

Comment: Do you have any control over the server side or is it a web service etc run by some third party? Does the server support `CORS`? Does it support `JSONP`? Which browsers does it need to work on? Does it need to work on mobile?

Comment: It's a mobile application develop by using PhoneGap, I was follow <http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/> tutorial and it's work but have to use GET method to send/receive data, I want POST method work.

Answer (score 0):

JSON doesn't support fetching data from external URL

However you can use JSONP.

Here is an explanation by another web author (not me) about it:

http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/

Comment: This is not true any more. Opera became the last of the major browsers to support [`CORS` (Cross-origin resource sharing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), though for Internet Explorer it's only supported in version 10. (8 and 9 have an alternative called [`XDomainRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060.aspx).) As well as requiring recent browser versions the server side must support an additional HTTP header, generally `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Comment: @hippietrail That assumes OP having control of the server side.

Comment: @vzwick: `JSONP` also requires server side report. I did want to mention such in my comment but ran out of space. I did ask the OP about it in a comment to the question above. The third option is of course to use a custom proxy, or a public one such as `YQL`.